# How do I build a Dyson Sphere?

Tags: dyson-sphere-program

I have a pretty far advanced base now in Dyson Sphere Program, but so far I actually didn't really try to build a dyson sphere, I didn't even put any solar sails into orbit as I vaguely remembered from a previous game that they were somewhat disappointing with only early upgrades. I also didn't have many power issues after paving both poles with solar panels.

I have reasearched the majority of the main tech tree now, though I'm still missing quite a bit of the upgrades tree. My plan was to start with massively expanding the production of everything, but I discovered that I didn't have enough solar panels after all. So I switched plans now and I want to create a dyson sphere for power generation before expanding my base even further. I set up the basic infrastucture for producing all components, but now I need to design the dyson sphere and scale up the entire thing.

The dyson sphere editor is kinda intimidating, and I don't think I understand what I'm doing there. There are a lot of options to design a sphere, so far I just put a ring of nodes two grid spaces apart from each other into the sphere. I tried to look up some hints on how to use this, but most people talking about it seem to be much further into the game than I am and try to do more fancy stuff.

I want to build the simplest sphere to provide a reasonable amount of power for the expansion of my base. I don't care about hyper-optimizing this, I just want a simple dyson sphere to get started. I have a whole bunch of aspects where I'm not sure what reasonable settings are:

- should the sphere, or rather the initial ring be in the same plane as my solar system or in another one?
- how big is a reasonable radius?
- how does the whole nodes stuff work? What patterns should I use there?
- where do I place the ejectors and receivers ideally?
- where do I shoot the solar sails, and how do they get into the sphere?

Comment: Pretty sure Elon Musk is wondering the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, a lot of questions here, let's tackle them one by one.

1. The actual angle isn't important. Eventually - if that's what you decide - you'll have a full globe *anyway*. That said, early on you don't have the technology to *create* a full globe -- you'll need to research increasing tiers of [Dyson Sphere Stress System](https://dyson-sphere-program.fandom.com/wiki/Dyson_Sphere_Stress_System_(Lv1)) to increase the maximum latidude *from your planned meridian* you can build to -- IE, if you designate your sphere to orbit at 30 degrees off the solar ecliptic, and you have one tier of DSSS researched, you'll be able to build from about +15 to +45.
2. I'm not *actually* 100% sure about the second and would have to test it out, but I think that a larger radius means you'll need more material to make the ring and shell - but also a higher maximum output. I recommend a nice big one around a star with a high luminosity factor.
3. You've got three basic components you're designating: Nodes, structure, and shells -- or basically, points, lines and filled-in areas. You need to place nodes close enough together that you're allowed to make structural braces between them, and then make a shell segment once you've enclosed an area. *How* you enclose an area is entirely up to you; if you want a nice even geometric shape you can switch to the triangular grid and make the nodes twelve triangles apart along straight lines.
4. Ejectors can be placed pretty much anywhere on any planet in the system as long as it faces toward the star at at least *some* point of its orbit -- so avoid the night side of tidally locked worlds, but otherwise you're good. Receivers will need a line of sight to the swarm and shell to function; at first you're going to have to reconcile yourself with periods of inactivity as you place them wherever, but once you invent gravity lensing then you can use the edge of the atmosphere to bend the incoming power transmission and the area above about 60 degrees latitude will, on any planet with a decent atmosphere, effectively draw power 100% of the time.
5. Solar sails are shot into a defined swarm orbit. You can specify swarm orbits in the same interface as your sphere, and the ejectors can be told which orbit to aim for. Once the actual structure is starting to form, sails will be pulled out of the swarms and into position on the shell automatically; no need to worry about those.

Comment: Thanks, when I posted the question I didn't have any of the reasearch that allows builder in more areas of the sphere. I didn't know that without it I could not even build anything useful, and it made it rather confusing, if not impossible to figure out how this works.

Comment: Oh, right, forgot about that.